# Deployment job on gitlab

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to make job for deployment on gitlab. I'm writing yaml file for it.

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8
testjob:
  script:
    - "apt-get update"
    - "apt-get install sshpass -y"
    - "echo installed"
    - "sshpass -p 'pass' ssh user@host"
    - "echo login successful"
    - "touch testfile.txt"
    - "echo finished"
```

But when I'm trying to login with sshpass and i'm getting en error

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

What the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by disabling Pseudo-tty allocation with option -T.